# Trying to install NPM for Node.JS using YUM

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am trying to get Node.JS working using [this tutorial.](http://blog.modulus.io/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs)  I have managed to get node.js installed throuhg PuTTy, using the command:

`yum install -y nodejs`

And that seemed to work fine (I might have had to use sudo, I can't remember now)

I am really new to command line interfaces so please bear with me.

I also ran (from another webpage):

`yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"`

Which also seemed to work fine, but didn't seem to install `npm` anywhere :(

Now, I can run and execute .js files from the command line using `node file.js`, and that seems to work fine.  But now I am stuck in the above tutorial where it says to install [Express.](http://expressjs.com/)  It says to run the command:

`npm install express`

Except I don't seem to have the command `npm`.  I read somewhere that it no longer comes with the latest version of Node.JS, so what can I do?  On all of my google searches, I can't seem to find a `yum` command to install `expressjs` or `npm`.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npm` is a package on his own and you need to install it sepatately from nodejs

```
sudo yum install nodejs npm
```

Where is a chance you'll need to use an EPEL repository (depends on your distro)

```
sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
```

BTW, official documentation on "Installing Node.js via package manager" located on official site:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Comment: THanks!! it seemed to work :)  I don't know how you knew that, I couldnt find anywhere telling me how.

Comment: ANd i've managed to run `npm instal express` too, and it worked!! And I made a type on there, but it stil worked? Thats odd..

Comment: @Chud37, in fact the link I've provided is on official [download page](http://nodejs.org/download/) in "Other info" section

Comment: Thank you, yes I didn't look that far down the page.  I should have done.  Sorry, but thank you so much for helping me.